# There is a basket with $3$ short straws and $2$ long straws (Average Number of Trials To Achieve a Result)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem I thought of, but I keep running into an issue.

The problem:

> There is a basket with $3$ short straws and $2$ long straws. Every
> time a straw is drawn from the basket, the straw is put back into the
> basket again. What is the average number of draws required to randomly
> draw a long straw $3$ times?

My thought process is that I should calculate the average number of draws by taking the probability of each individual occurrence and multiplying it by the number of draws associated with that occurrence. For example, there is a $0.4^3$ chance that the draw will be long straw, long straw, long straw, and since the number of draws associated with the occurrence is $3$, I would add $0.4^3 * 3$ to my average.

However, the problem I run into with this approach is that there is an infinite number of patterns since the pattern could be short, short, short... infinitely.

Is there something that I'm missing here or is the answer a lot simpler than I'm making it out to be?

Comment: Please see Expected Value section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution Probability of drawing long straw is $p = 2/5$. Now use the formula $E(X) = n p$ where $E(X) = 3$ and you need to find $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $E_n$ is the average number of draws required to randomly draw a long straw $n$ times. So what the question asks is $E_3$.

At the very beginning, you have 0 times to draw a long straw. In the first draw, you have $2/5$ probability to get a long straw (which means only 2 long straws are needed after this draw), and $3/5$ probability to get a short straw (which means you still need $3$ straws). So you can see

$$
E_3 = 1 + {2\over5}E_2 + {3\over 5}E_3
$$

You can get the following equations using the way I mentioned above:

$$
E_2 = 1 + {2\over5}E_1 + {3\over 5}E_2\\
E_1 = 1 + {2\over5}E_0 + {3\over 5}E_1\\
$$

$E_0=0$, so you can solve this equation and get
$$
E_1={5\over2},E_2=5,E_3={15\over2}
$$
so the answer is $15\over2$.